# Execute a SQL Server stored procedure from MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, ms-access-2013

I use MS Access 2013 and SQL Server 2012. I have connected my SQL Server database to MS Access. I connect to SQL Server via SQL Server Authentication. I want to execute a stored procedure with a value entered into a textbox in one of my forms. I have been trying to do it for ages now but nothing that I found on this website works for me. Can anyone please help me and give me some tips as to how to write a basic VBA code to execute the procedure? Please help!!!

Comment: Did you try creating a pass-through query using a DAO.QueryDef object?

Comment: @gord thompson No I didn't, and I have no idea how to do this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the most straightforward way is to create a temporary pass-through query using a DAO.QueryDef object. If you have an existing linked table in Access then you can use its `.Connect` property (ODBC connection information). All you need to do is set the `.SQL` property of the QueryDef to call (EXEC) the stored procedure, like this:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")
    ' get .Connect property from existing ODBC linked table
    qdf.Connect = cdb.TableDefs("dbo_myContacts").Connect
    qdf.sql = "EXEC dbo.addContact N'" & Replace(Me.Text0.Value, "'", "''") & "'"
    qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
    qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

So, for example, if the Text0 text box contains `Thompson` then the QueryDef will execute

```sql
EXEC dbo.addContact N'Thompson'
```

and if the text box contains `O'Rourke` then the QueryDef will execute

```sql
EXEC dbo.addContact N'O''Rourke'
```

Answer (score 2):

After Trial and error this one worked for me

```
 > Private Sub UpdateItems_Click()
    >     Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    >     Set cdb = CurrentDb
    >     Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")
    >     ' get .Connect property from existing ODBC linked table
    >     qdf.Connect = cdb.TableDefs("dbo_AccesLinkedTable").Connect
    >     qdf.SQL = "EXEC dbo.YourStoreProcedure"
    >     qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
    >     qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
    >     Set qdf = Nothing
    >     Set cdb = Nothing
    > 
    >  MsgBox "Records Updated!"
    > 
    > End Sub
```