# Access via ODBC to a SQL procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have an Access database connected via ODBC to a SQL Server backend.
In the SQL Server database, I have a stored procedure called `Empty_Table`.

The procedure does only this:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE
```

(The table should only be emptied).

How can I access this procedure in an Access database and execute it in the SQL Server database?

Thanks

Comment: This one looks related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593222/execute-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-from-ms-access

Answer (score 1):

Create a pass-through query in Access, with the command `EXEC Empty_Table`.

More information on pass-through queries can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pass-through-query-b775ac23-8a6b-49b2-82e2-6dac62532a42).

Answer (score 0):

Well, as suggested, you create a pass-though query in Access.

Then in VBA code, you can do this:

```
 currentdb.QueryDefs("abc").Execute
```

And if  you want to execute different server side commands, then you can do this:

```
with Currentdb.QueryDefs("MyPtQuery")
    .SQL = "exec dbo.MyStorProce"
    .Execute
end with
```

And since I tend to have ONE PT query, and I use it over and over in code?
And if that stored procedure returns data/records? then you can do this:

```
dim rstData      as DAO.RecordSet

with Currentdb.QueryDefs("MyPtQuery").
    .SQL = "exec dbo.MyStorProce"
    .ReturnsRecords = true
    Set rstData = .OpenRecordSet
end with
```